# Why does Remove device not show up on Devices and printers?

Tags: windows-7, printer

The printer is in my `Devices and printers`, and when highlighting/clicking on this printer, `Remove device` does not show up. When looking at other questions, I followed the instructions to try and remove it using `Control panel > Admin tools > Print Management > All Printers`, then selecting my printer, right clicking on my printer and selecting `Delete.

This did resolve deleting the printer from this list, only it still shows up in my `Devices and Printers` and still without the option to `Remove device` after selecting that printer. Also in `Print Management`, there are no printers in Printers not ready, nor in Printers with jobs. I do still have this printer's driver, which I suppose I could delete, but I don't know if this will resolve the job.

Comment: Did the printer installation/addition to Windows Control Panel involve any customer installer? The problem is that if a custom installer has been used, the registry might still have the printer's data and driver location info, which are making the printer visible. But because the actual data has been deleted, there is nothing to use for the printer. I suggest you try and find any installer that has been used and remove the printer using that.

Answer (score 0):

To completely delete the driver do this:

Click on any other printer in Devices & Printers. Then click on "Print server properties" which will appear in the menu bar at the top. Next click on the Drivers tab and remove the printer from the list.

As to why "Remove device" does not show up, maybe someone else can tell you that.